# Want to switch the SIM card from my iPhone 4 to 6s plus

Tags: sim

I want to insert my existing SIM card from iPhone 4 to iPhone 6s Plus. I want to know if I remove the SIM card from my existing phone, will the data and photos and contacts and whatsApp chats will be deleted or will it remain in the phone? Please guide me on this.

Comment: iirc , the SIMs are different sizes, so unless you have one that each size can snap out of its parent, you'll need a new SIM.

Comment: @Tetsujin, while the SIM cards are indeed different sizes, the iPhone 4 size can be trimmed down to iPhone 6S+ usually using a dedicated tool (or scissors and careful cutting).

Comment: The data that you want to keep (photos, contacts, etc), is this on the iPhone 4? And you want it on the iPhone 6S+? Or, are you swapping SIM cards but keeping the same phone? The answer depends on what you're exactly doing, which is unclear from your question. This is because the data that you've listed all live on the phone, not the SIM.

Answer (score 1):

If you used iCloud in your iPhone 4, it's most likely you will still have your contacts and photos in your 6S Plus if you'll use the same iCloud account. If purchased music from iTunes and apps from the App Store, you will still be able to have them on your new phone. However, chat message history depends on the app developer. Some have servers to save your messages in and make them available in case the app is installed in another phone/platform (like Skype), and some just save your messages locally (on your phone) which makes them unavailable to other installations of the app.

Comment: Thanku but my iCloud account is not active